# Coding problem using a 2-d array of structs inside another struct in C

Tags: c, arrays, struct

I am working with a 2-dimensional array of structs which is a part of another struct. It's not something I've done a lot with so I'm having a problem. This function ends up failing after getting to the "test" for-loop near the end. It prints out one line correctly before it seg faults.

The parts of my code which read data into a dummy 2-d array of structs works just fine, so it must be my assigning array to be part of another struct (the imageStruct).

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
/*the structure of each pixel*/
typedef struct
{
 int R,G,B;
}pixelStruct;

/*data for each image*/
typedef struct
{ 
 int height;
 int width;
 pixelStruct *arr; /*pointer to 2-d array of  pixels*/
} imageStruct;


imageStruct ReadImage(char * filename)
{
 FILE *image=fopen(filename,"r");
 imageStruct thisImage;

        /*get header data from image*/

        /*make a 2-d array of of pixels*/
 pixelStruct imageArr[thisImage.height][thisImage.width];

        /*Read in the image. */

        /*I know this works because I after storing the image data in the
          imageArr array, I printed each element from the array to the
          screen.*/

 /*so now I want to take the array called imageArr and put it in the
   imageStruct called thisImage*/

  thisImage.arr = malloc(sizeof(imageArr));
  //allocate enough space in struct for the image array. 

 *thisImage.arr = *imageArr; /*put imageArr into the thisImage imagestruct*/

//test to see if assignment worked: (this is where it fails)

 for (i = 0; i < thisImage.height; i++)
 {
  for (j = 0; j < thisImage.width; j++)
  {
   printf("\n%d: R: %d G: %d B: %d\n", i ,thisImage.arr[i][j].R,
          thisImage.arr[i][j].G, thisImage.arr[i][j].B);
  }
 } 

 return thisImage;
}
```

(In case you are wondering why I am using a dummy array in the first place, well it's because when I started writing this code, I couldn't figure out how to do what I am trying to do now.)

EDIT: One person suggested that I didn't initialize my 2-d array correctly in the typedef for the imageStruct. Can anyone help me correct this if it is indeed the problem?

Comment: An aside: if you're working with pixels you might want to consider a flat linear buffer, then index point (x,y) with buffer[y*width + x].  That's pretty commonly done, and might be beneficial if you ever have to pass that buffer to someone else's code that might assume such a format.

Comment: Thank you for the advice! I will consider that. Then I could just forget this mess with the 2d arrays!

Comment: I've concluded that there is no hope in trying to make a 2-D array part of a struct. I've switched to a 1-D array and everything is working out now. Thanks to everyone who helped me out, this is by far the most helpful programming forum I have ever come across!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You seem to be able to create variable-length-arrays, so you're on a C99 system, or on a system that supports it.  But not all compilers support those.  If you want to use those, you don't need the `arr` pointer declaration in your struct.  Assuming no variable-length-arrays, let's look at the relevant parts of your code:

```
/*data for each image*/
typedef struct
{ 
    int height;
    int width;
    pixelStruct *arr; /*pointer to 2-d array of  pixels*/
} imageStruct;
```

`arr` is a pointer to `pixelStruct`, and not to a 2-d array of pixels.  Sure, you can use `arr` to access such an array, but the comment is misleading, and it hints at a misunderstanding.  If you really wish to declare such a variable, you would do something like:

```
pixelStruct (*arr)[2][3];
```

and `arr` would be a pointer to an "array 2 of array 3 of pixelStruct", which means that `arr` points to a 2-d array.  This isn't really what you want.  To be fair, this isn't what you declare, so all is good.  But your comment suggests a misunderstanding of pointers in C, and that is manifested later in your code.

At this point, you will do well to read a good introduction to arrays and pointers in C, and a really nice one is [C For Smarties: Arrays and Pointers](http://web.torek.net/torek/c/pa.html) by Chris Torek.  In particular, please make sure you understand the first diagram on the page and everything in the definition of the function `f` there.

Since you want to be able to index `arr` in a natural way using "column" and "row" indices, I suggest you declare `arr` as a pointer to pointer.  So your structure becomes:

```
/* data for each image */
typedef struct
{ 
    int height;
    int width;
    pixelStruct **arr; /* Image data of height*width dimensions */
} imageStruct;
```

Then in your `ReadImage` function, you allocate memory you need:

```
int i;
thisImage.arr = malloc(thisImage.height * sizeof *thisImage.arr);
for (i=0; i < thisImage.height; ++i)
    thisImage.arr[i] = malloc(thisImage.width * sizeof *thisImage.arr[i]);
```

Note that for clarity, I haven't done any error-checking on `malloc`.  In practice, you should check if `malloc` returned `NULL` and take appropriate measures.

Assuming all the memory allocation succeeded, you can now read your image in `thisImage.arr` (just like you were doing for `imageArr` in your original function).

Once you're done with `thisImage.arr`, make sure to free it:

```
for (i=0; i < thisImage.height; ++i)
    free(thisImage.arr[i]);

free(thisImage.arr);
```

In practice, you will want to wrap the allocation and deallocation parts above in their respective functions that allocate and free the `arr` object, and take care of error-checking.

Comment: Wow, thanks for such an in-depth answer! You're absolutely right that I have a poor understanding of C pointers. I think my problem is completely solved now. Thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

I don't think `sizeof imageArr` works as you expect it to when you're using runtime-sized arrays. Which, btw, are a sort of "niche" C99 feature. You should add some printouts of crucial values, such as that `sizeof` to see if it does what you think.

Clearer would be to use explicit allocation of the array:

```
thisImage.arr = malloc(thisImage.width * thisImage.height * sizeof *thisImage.arr);
```

I also think that it's hard (if even possible) to implement a "true" 2D array like this. I would recommend just doing the address computation yourself, i.e. accessing a pixel like this:

```
unsigned int x = 3, y = 1; // Assume image is larger.
print("pixel at (%d,%d) is r=%d g=%d b=%d\n", x, y, thisImage.arr[y * thisImage.width + x]);
```

I don't see how the required dimension information can be associated with an array at run-time; I don't think that's possible.

Comment: If height=10 and width=1, and each spot on the matrix has 3 ints for the pixelStruct struct, then each slot should be 3*4 = 12 bytes, so for the full matrix it's 120... Am I correct? If so, then my code "sizeof imageArr" works fine. I tried your code, but sizeof *thisImage.arr comes out to 4. When I replaced my malloc code with yours, I got the exact same results. Thanks for your help so far!

Comment: If sizeof *thisImage.arr is four, then there's something wrong with the code you showed. It should be the size of the pointed-to data, i.e. sizeof (pixelStruct). Did you include the star?

Comment: Yes, you are right. I had changed the declaration from pixelstruct *arr to pixelstruct **arr. So now it comes out to 12 and 120, but that's the same result as my original malloc. Thanks.

Comment: I guess that was my problem. It just wouldn't work out as a 2-d array. Thanks for all your input! I am switching to 1-d.

Answer (score 0):

height and width are undefined; you might want to initialise them first, as in

`thisImage.height = 10; thisImage.width = 20;`

also,

- what is colorRGB?

Comment: Height and width are things I defined in the section of code I took out in the part that says "get header data of image". There is no problem with these values.

ColorRGB was the original name of my pixelStruct structure. I did a find and replace to change it but I missed one.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

it looks like you are trying to copy array by assignment.
You cannot use simple assignment operator to do that, you have to use some function to copy things, for example memcpy.

```
*thisImage.arr = *imageArr;
thisimage.arr[0] = imagearr[0];
```

The above statements are doing the same thing.
However this is not most likely what causes the memory corruption

since you are working with two dimensional arrays, do make sure you initialize them correctly.
Looking at the code, should not even compile: the array is declared as one-dimensional in your image structure but you refer to as two-dimensional?

Comment: How do I declare the array as 2-D in the image structure? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

`*thisImage.arr = *imageArr; /*put imageArr into the thisImage imagestruct*`

This won't work. You have to declare arr as `colorRGB **`, allocate it accordingly, etc.